# Combine two tables unique column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like shown as below:

```
mysql> select*from receipt;                                                                                
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | receipt_id | money | created_at          |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | receipt_3  |   100 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|  2 | receipt_4  |   200 | 2018-10-29 00:00:00 |
|  3 | receipt_5  |   300 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select*from material;
+----+------------+---------------------+
| id | receipt_id | created_at          |
+----+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | receipt_3  | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|  2 | receipt_3  | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|  3 | receipt_5  | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
+----+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have got the result use this: "select distinct sum(money),`material`.`created_at` from `receipt` inner join `material` on `receipt`.`receipt_id`=`material`.`receipt_id` group by `material`.`created_at`;"

```
+------------+---------------------+
| sum(money) | created_at          |
+------------+---------------------+
|        200 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|        300 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but I want to get this with ignoring same record:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| sum(money) | created_at          |
+------------+---------------------+
|        100 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|        300 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Have thought for a long time but no answer,please help ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `DISTINCT` for `material` in a subquery ignoring same record then `JOIN`

```
SELECT sum(r.money),t1.created_at
FROM (
    select DISTINCT receipt_id,created_at   
    from material
)t1 JOIN receipt r on t1.receipt_id = r.receipt_id  
GROUP BY t1.created_at
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.With your help, I solved the problem ^ ^)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sum(distinct money)` :

```
select sum(distinct money) as sum_money,
       m.created_at 
  from receipt r join material m 
    on r.receipt_id=m.receipt_id 
 group by m.created_at;

+------------+---------------------+
| sum_money  | created_at          |
+------------+---------------------+
|        100 | 2018-10-30 00:00:00 |
|        300 | 2018-10-31 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

[***DB-Fiddle Demo***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/72AzULQZ6Y5vKc7ypNd7dP/0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Maybe my question now quite clear.However,got solved.